# Testing with Django client multiple checkboxes

Tags: python, django-forms, django-testing

I read recently a book about TDD in Python and figured I could start to follow this pattern.

But the first problem has already appeared and I can't seem to be able to fix it.

[HTML form (declared in forms.py)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wBH7a.png)

When I POST and print it, I get the following output:

`<QueryDict: {'csrfmiddlewaretoken': ['...'], 'personal_interests': ['3', '1']}>`

In order to test this view, into the tests (using Django client) I have already tried so far:

`response = self.client.post('/',
    data={'reading': False,
          'investing': True,
          'traveling': True})`

`response = self.client.post('/', {'personal_interests': ['3', '1']})`

Also tried as a tuple:

`response = self.client.post('/', {'personal_interests': ('3', '1'),})`

But none of these, seem to send the data I want to send.

Thanks in advance.

views.py:

```python
def home_page(request):
    default_customer, _ = Customer.objects.get_or_create(name="John", surname="Doe")
    default_customer.interests.clear()
    form = InterestsForm()
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = InterestsForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            for key, value in form.cleaned_data.items():
                for interest in value:
                    filtered_interest, _ = Category.objects.get_or_create(name=interest)
                    default_customer.interests.add(filtered_interest)
            default_customer.save()
            return redirect('/user/'+str(default_customer.id)+'/interests')
        else:
            messages.error(request, "An error has occured. Check all the fields.")
            return redirect('/')
    context = {'form': form}
    return render(request, 'home.html', context)


forms.py:

class InterestsForm(forms.Form):
    personal_interests = forms.ModelMultipleChoiceField(
     widget=forms.CheckboxSelectMultiple,
     queryset=Category.objects.all().order_by('name'),
     required=False,
     label='Interests')

    class Meta:
        model = Category
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have figured where was the error... Test database and normal database are different so I lacked the objects created in the database while testing.

So all I needed to do was to create the items, and then send the POST

`response = self.client.post('/', {'personal_interests': ['3', '1']})` WORKS where '3' and '1' are the pks of the objects.

Here is the fixed code.

```python
def test_can_save_a_POST_request(self):
        Customer.objects.get_or_create(name="John", surname="Doe")
        reading_interest, _ = Category.objects.get_or_create(name="reading")
        investing_interest, _ = Category.objects.get_or_create(name="investing")
        traveling_interest, _ = Category.objects.get_or_create(name="traveling")

        post_data = {'personal_interests': [str(investing_interest.id),
         str(traveling_interest.id)]}

        response = self.client.post('/',
        data=post_data)

        new_customer = Customer.objects.first()
        customer_interests = [category.name for category in new_customer.interests.all()]

        self.assertNotIn('reading', customer_interests)
        self.assertIn('traveling', customer_interests)
        self.assertIn('investing', customer_interests)
```